# Check name is unique if not append

Tags: php, unique, increment, identifier

My application requires the user to enter their business name, which the application will automatically create into a unique identifier to be used in URLs, ie

"Bob's Cafe" will become "bobs-cafe"

But if there are duplicate names I would like the application to add a number so if there is already a "bobs-cafe" we will use "bobs-cafe-1" and likewise if there is already a "bobs-cafe-1" we will use "bobs-cafe-2"

Ive used explode and also looked at a regular expressions but I dont know the best way to approach this.

Im stuck in being able to grab the number and incrementing it and returning the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not to add an autoincrement number to every identifier in the URL?
Just like SO does:

stackoverflow.com/questions/**2895334**/php-application-check-name-is-unique-if-not-append

so, you have both unique identifier and a business name.

This is even better because they are free to change their business name, without changing an identifier.

As for your question it's very simple. Just for the PHP practice:

```
if (/* you've found the name is already non unique and have the max one in the $id */) {
  $parts = explode("-",$id);
  if (isset($parts[1])) $newid = $parts[0]."-".($parts[1]+1);
  else $newid = $parts[0]."-1";
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the best approach if this sort of URL structure is allowed.  Otherwise, force the user to provide a unique business name, or cause the URL to be unique by putting the business's city and/or state in the URL as well.

Comment: Oh god, I hate how you do conditionals. :)

Comment: @user Though it won't work in your case, I just notice that you're using same delimiter for the name and for the number, it is better to have different, so it not to be mixed. Though it's just a example to the method.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Sarfraz's answer, you might want to find it using a LIKE statement

```
SELECT `urlIdentifier` FROM `businesses` WHERE `urlIdentifier` LIKE `bobs-cafe%`
```

which will get all the bobs-cafe items - that way, if you get 5 rows you know you have

```
bobs-cafe
bobs-cafe-1
bobs-cafe-2
bobs-cafe-3
bobs-cafe-4
```

and that you'll need to add bobs-cafe-5

EDIT - Or this:

```
SELECT count(*)  as `howMany` FROM `businesses` WHERE `urlIdentifier` LIKE `bobs-cafe%`
```

Now your result object ( or array ) will have the total number:

echo $resultObject->howMany; // number of bobs-cafe sql found

Comment: throw in an ORDER BY DESC and limit 1 to get the max at once

Comment: Though that would require analyzing the string returned to grab the number. Adding on to my answer for another option..

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I think using the id and the identifier in the URL is a great idea.

Further to the above though, that's not the issue, it's more how I determine from the string the current increment number then increasing it

Comment: This is a good idea, but you should separate the actual business ID (bobs-cafe) from the number somehow. Your code would fail if someone tried to register "Bob's Cafe and Bakery" because "bobs-cafe-and-bakery" is `LIKE` "bobs-cafe%".

Comment: Good point musicfreak - using a different delimiter for the id like bobs-cafe::1 so you could do LIKE 'bobs-cafe::%' to specify it's the entire 'business-name'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$user` is already in the form `bobs-cafe`

```
function username_exists ( $user ) {

      $result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table WHERE $name LIKE '$user%' ");
      $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if ( $result ) {

            $num = $count+1;
            return username_exists ( $user.'-'.$num ) ;

        } else {

            return $user;
        }

}
```

Comment: See my comment on @Dan Heberden's solution above: This is a good idea, but you should separate the actual business ID (bobs-cafe) from the number somehow. Your code would fail if someone tried to register "Bob's Cafe and Bakery" because "bobs-cafe-and-bakery" is `LIKE` "bobs-cafe%".

Comment: i think the whole approch here is wrong, anyway the function assume you have only one separator! a good id can't be abstract-abstract-1 must be IMHO a number or at least something like firstname_lastname#